# the vertical scroll to switch desktop is not working

Tags: kubuntu

The vertical scroll to switch desktop is not working how do i enable it.
this has been the case seance 20.10
kde plasma 5.21.4
kde framework 5.80.0
qt 5.15.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue than you for quite a long time. This solution worked for me

https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/fy1uwk/verticalscroll_desktop_switching_issues/

Go to desktop folder settings (right click on desktop > configure desktop > wallpaper) and change layout from "folder view" to "desktop"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173498)

Comment: this is a answer but it change how you use the desktop a lot so its not a answer for me.